# OLAP Realtime querying for huge volume data - options

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, presto, druid, nosql

We have an OLAP table with 180 billion rows and 100+ columns, and the volume is close to 8TB in Hive. Most of the columns are dimensions and also we have few metrics columns also. We would like to build a real-time system  support ad-hoc queries to run the dashboard applications, where the queries should be executed in sub 10 seconds latency.

We are now looking for the options to build such a real-time adhoc querying system, and we are checking about the possible options and actually struggling to choose a correct system. We are seeing about

**Presto** , can used to query hdfs directly, But we are not sure if it will support low latency queries over such huge volumes.

**Cassandra**, to build preaggregated views according to the queries.

**Druid**, to build preaggregated views and looks interesting, but seems doesn't have any enterprise support.

Here we are actually struggling to make a choice from these components and also we are not sure if we missed any other relevant tools that may suite for this requirement.

We are looking for the tool/database that can closely interact with HDFS, we can also consider any other tool if it read performance is good for large volumes.

I kindly request your help in guiding me about the component selection and also please advice me if I have to see about any other tools.

Comment: This is a very complex subject, and really depends on the query shape, queries per second, required update rate, required consistency and so on.  I'm not sure anyone can recommend a system without having a detailed understanding of these requirements.

Comment: I can tell you at FB, we use Presto for many applications like like this, but we use the open source Presto Raptor storage system on flash, or a custom closed source backed based on sharded mysql.  In one system based on Raptor we have works on much larger data, and runs about 100-200 queries/min with hourly loads on low 100s of machines.

Comment: Thank you so much @DainSundstrom. I shall update my question with more details. However, Can you please let me know if the read performance of Presto over Cassandra will be faster than using over Hive?.

Comment: Imply.io prvoides the professional support of Druid.  At my work, I use both Presto and Druid.  Druid ingests stream from Kafka.  At the same time the same stream is written into Hive/HDFS in Parquet format.  Presto can query the Hive.  Druid can ingest the Parquet for recalculation of the historical data.  They are complementary.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as you can see here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Druid+Integration druid is getting integrated closely with Hive and that will enable to fully support your use cases, where some of the data can be queried from a fast data store like druid and heavy weight queries with complex join can go to Hive.
Also note that from the listed solutions above, only druid has a robust (sub second latency) realtime ingestion firehose integrating kafka, storm, flink rabitMQ and the list goes on and on...
From the support point of view note that druid has a very vibrant open source community plus it is used by hundred of companies including big ones like  Yahoo NetFlix .... in addition there is at least 2 companies that will be providing enterprise supports, namely Hortonworks and Imply.

Comment: wow.  I wasn't aware of the Hive-Druid integration.  As the link indicated the feature is looking to be introduced in Hive 2.2.0.